# how to return a specific type from a variant using a visitor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, std-variant

I have the code below and why `visitor1` and `visitor2` gives errors?
Does that mean the visitor cannot return one type within the variant?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>


struct Visitor1
{
    template <class T>
    T operator()(const T & t) const
    {
        return (t);
    }
};

struct Visitor2
{
    int operator()(const int  & t) const
    {
        return std::get<int>(t);
    }

    char operator()(const char & t) const
    {
        return std::get<char>(t);
    }
};

struct Visitor3
{
    void operator()(const int & t) const
    {
        std::cout<<t;
    }
    void operator()(const char & t) const
    {
        std::cout<<t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, char> v{char(100)};

    std::visit(Visitor3{}, v);

    auto t = std::visit(Visitor2{}, v);  //fails
    //auto t = std::visit(Visitor1{}, v); //fails
    std::cout << t;
}
```

I know I can use `std::get()`, but the issue is I can only use `auto` with `std::get()`, if I do something like below, the `x` is not accessible outside of the if/else scope:

```
bool b;
Variant v;
if (b)
{
   auto x = std::get<int>(v);
}
else
{
   auto x = std::get<char>(v);
}
// I want to do something with x here out of if/else
```

Comment: What you want is only doable with dynamic polymorphism, as opposed to the static polymorphism that `std::variant` offers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with x? Most likely you'll be able to do with using variant itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the code below and why visitor1 and visitor2 gives errors?

Because C++ is a strongly typed language.

When you write

```
auto t = std::visit(Visitor2{}, v);  //fails
```

the compiler **must** decide compile-time which type is `t`, so **must** decide which type return `std::visit(Visitor2{}, v)`.

If `Visitor2` return a `char`, when `v` contains a `char`, or a `int`, when `v` contain a `int`, the compiler can't choose (compile-time!) the type returned from `std::visit()` [there is also the problem (`Visitor2` only) that `t`, inside `operator()`'s, is a `int` or a `char`, so you can't apply `std::get()` to it].

Same problem with `Visitor1`: the template `operator()` return the template type so `int` or `char` for a `std::variant<int, char>`.

`Visitor3` works because both `operator()` return `void`, so the compiler can resolve (compile-time) that `std::visit(Visitor3{}, v)` return (in a sense) `void`.

Maybe is better explained in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

> [`std::visit()`] Effectively returns
>
> ```
> std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(vis), std::get<is>(std::forward<Variants>(vars))...)
> ```
>
> , where `is...` is `vars.index()...`. The return type is deduced from the returned expression as if by `decltype`.
>
> **The call is ill-formed if the invocation above is not a valid expression of the same type and value category, for all combinations of alternative types of all variants**.

Answer (score 3):

A language could exist with many features of C++ that does what you want.

In order to do what you want, when you call `std::visit`, N different implementations of the rest of the function would have to be written.

In each of those N different implementations (2 in your case), the type of a variable would be different.

C++ doesn't work that way.

The only part of code that is "multiplied" by the visit call is the visitor.

```
int main()
{
  std::variant<int, char> v{char(100)};

  std::visit([&](auto && t){
    std::cout << t;
  }, v);
}
```

I put *the rest of the body of the function* within the visitor.  That code is instantiated once for every type that can be stored within the visitor.

Anything that *returns* from the visit goes back to the "single instance" body of the calling scope.

Basically, `[&](auto&& t)` lambdas do what you seem to want.

---

Now, we can do some tricks to change the syntax a bit.

My favorite is:

```
v->*visit*[&](auto&& val) {
  std::cout << val;
  return [val](auto&& x) { x << val; };
}->*visit*[&](auto&& outputter) {
  outputer(std::cout);
};
```

where `->*visit*` uses a relatively ridiculous amount of metaprogramming to allow

1. Named operators to cause visiting,
2. Fusing the return values of the visits into a variant.

but no sane person would write that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
bool b;
Variant v;
std_optional<char> x_char;
std_optional<int> x_int;
if (b)
{
   x_int = std::get<int>(v);
}
else
{
   x_char = std::get<char>(v);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the OP clearly written "I know I can use `std::get()`, but the issue is I can only use `auto` with `std::get()`, if I do something like below, the `x` is not accessible outside of the if/else scope"

Comment: `I can only use auto with std::get()` is not true

Comment: Sorry: you're right: your solution solve this particular problem.